# ToolStripMenuItem Clear Method - will it remove also subitems?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, toolstripdropdown, toolstripmenu

Will `myStrip.DropDownItems.Clear()` remove also SubItems?

```
mystrip
   - Item1
        - SubItem1
             - AnotherSubItem1
   - Item2
```

After `Clear()` method

will it be just:

```
mystrip
```

or

```
mystrip
   - NOTHING HERE
        - SubItem1
              - AnotherSubItem1
```

Thanks for respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the objects will not be destroyed or disposed, but you cannot access them any more by the DropDrownItems list. so if you have no reference anywhere else to the items, the garbage collection will take care about it